# How to focus on input opened in an overlay that is not in the same parent element as the trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search input that is displayed in an overlay on the page. I display that overlay with a simple toggle class function, but when I try to focus on the input along with the overlay activation, it doesn't work and, on mobile for example, the keyboard doesn't open when I toggle the search overlay and if I manually focus the input, when I close the overlay the keyboard remains active.

One mention, the trigger is not in the same html element as the input.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#search-lens").click(function(){ 
          $("#search-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
          // this is the input id
          $("#main-search").focus();
    });

    $("#search-close").click(function(){        
        $("#search-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
        $("#main-search").blur();   
    }); 
});
```

I expect the input to be focused when I click #search-lens and to blur when I click #search-close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `.trigger()`

Use `.trigger('focus')` and `.trigger('blur')`.

### Demo

```js
$(".open").click(function() {
  $(".dialog").fadeIn();
  $('.key').trigger('focus');
});

$(".close").click(function() {
  $(".dialog").fadeOut();
  $('.key').trigger('blur');
});
```

```html
<button class='open' type='button'>Open</button>

<section class='dialog' style='display:none'>

  <input class='key' type='search'>
  <button class='search' type='button'>Search</button>
  <button class='close' type='button'>&times;</button>

</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It actually works only once and only on loading the page, if you try to open and close couple of times, it doesn't work anymore. Also, if that input is not the first one on page, it doesn't work.

Autofocus only works when you load the page the first time, by the time you click somewhere else, or click several times on the show/hide search, it stops working.